# Sequalize filtering on sub sub models

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to filter on a sub sub model, for that I'm doing the following filter:

```
await models.Event.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: models.SubEvent,
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Game,
          where: {
            [models.Sequelize.Op.or]: {
              player1Team1Id: args.playerId,
              player2Team1Id: args.playerId,
              player1Team2Id: args.playerId,
              player2Team2Id: args.playerId
            }
          },
          required: true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

The model structure is as following: A `Event.hasMany(SubEvent)` and `SubEvent.hasMany(Game)`

but the following gives me all the events.
not the one where the player matches

Any suggestions on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause is malformed, so probably Sequelize is ignoring it (you could confirm by looking at the generate SQL).  `OR` needs to be an array of objects as shown below.

```
 where: {
    [models.Sequelize.Op.or]: 
      [
         {player1Team1Id: args.playerId},
         {player2Team1Id: args.playerId},
         {player1Team2Id: args.playerId},
         {player2Team2Id: args.playerId}
      ]
  },
```

Strange there was no exception.

hth